# How could strtok store outside of the string argument?

Tags: c, strtok, c11

One of the two problems that the `strtok_s` function (C11) solves is it prevents storing outside of the input string. As I understand it this would only be possible if you pass a non null terminated string to `strtok`.

Is it correct that if I only ever pass properly null terminated strings to `strtok` then there isn't a risk of it writing outside of the input string?

Comment: If it would not be so the function would not be included in the C Standard.

Comment: "...a risk of it writing outside..." do you mean to ask about **reading** outside? `strtok` doesn't do any writing at all, even within the input string.

Comment: @ArthurTacca You are wrong. The function changes the input string.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Oops you are right, I am wrong. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please read [**Field Experience With Annex K — Bounds Checking Interfaces**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm) before using any of the optional Annex K functions as they don't really make your code any safer.  Note this part especially: "As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable."

Comment: @cholz a string is null terminated by definition.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes I know that. I'm interpreting this to mean that `strtok_s` has been extended to allow an arbitrary character array as input and not just a c-string.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I'm interpreting this to mean that `strtok_s` accepts arbitrary character arrays as input and not just 'proper' C style strings.

Comment: @cholz without a nul terminator how can `strtok_s` know when to stop scanning?

Comment: @WeatherVane it takes a parameter `strmax` that points to the size of the input array.

Comment: @cholz the C standard annex K refers to the input argument as a *string*. As far as I am aware, the length constraint is a safety feature. Passing an unterminated array isn't described.

Comment: @WeatherVane But if it's a _string_ then it's null terminated and no extra length parameter is required. Which gets back to my original question: since `strtok` only accepts _strings_ then there is no way that it would write outside of the space allocated (after the null terminator).

Comment: It is to protect the **token length**, not so you can pass an unterminated string. *"The end of the token found shall occur within the first `*s1max` characters of `s1` for the first call, and shall occur within the first `*s1max` characters of where searching resumes on subsequent calls."* That can't be limiting the string length, because it is from where the previous token was found (or the start of the string for the first token), and so can theoretically extend past the input string's nul terminator.

Comment: @WeatherVane where did you find that information? The [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) that I am looking at says `strmax` is a pointer to an object which initially holds the size of str: `strtok_s` stores the number of characters that remain to be examined. So `strtok_s` will modify `strmax` not to point past the end of the string?

Comment: It's a direct quote from the C17 Standard. But you may be right, it goes on to say *"The first call stores an initial value in the object pointed to by `ptr` and updates the value pointed to by`s1max` to reflect the number of elements that remain in relation to `ptr`."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start answering to the main question, about `strtok` writing beyond the size of the buffer containing the string.

1. `strtok` actually modifies the input string: it writes a string terminator (`'\0'`) where  the delimiter character used to be. In this way it can return to the user null-terminated tokens
2. In case a **bad input** is provided (a buffer in which the string terminator is missing) it could write beyond the input buffer size. It would read until a `'\0'` is found in memory and write data if before the end is reached a delimiter is found

---

Now, we cannot say properly that *"`strtok_s` prevents storing outside of the input string"* but we can say that this function provides a way to control the number of bytes of the input string that are examined, and as a consequence *written* (as explained above).

The control we are talking about is the same we have using `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`: we can pass to `strtok_s` the maximum size if the input string avoiding memory corruption **in case of missing string terminator**.

Let's have a look to [`strtok_s()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) signature:

```
char *strtok_s(char *restrict str, rsize_t *restrict strmax,
               const char *restrict delim, char **restrict ptr);
```

Comparing it to `strtok`'s interface, we have two more parameters. The `ptr` parameter is useful to make it reentrant and it is present also in `strtok_r`. It is not directly related to this question.

The `strmax` parameter is the one we are looking about

> **strmax**    -   pointer to an object **which initially holds the size of str**: strtok_s stores the number of characters that remain to be examined

(the emphasis is mine).

So, passing to `strmax` the pointer to a variable initialized with the size of the char buffer containing the input string, will make sure that a write beyond that size will ever occur.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. The `strmax` parameter essentially extends `strtok` to allow arbitrary character arrays as input and not just null terminated strings.

Comment: @cholz I also edited to answer directly to your title question